# How to pass a valid CSRF token to AdonisJs using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, adonis.js

I am using datatable edit and delete button and performing CURD operation
but request can't get jquery ajax post id...

**code**
**Controller: QuestionController**

```
async findby({ request, response}) {
    response.send(request.input('id'));
  }
```

**Jquery AJAX Post Request Code**

```
function QuestionEdit(id) {
  $.post(origin+'/dashboard/api/questions/findby', {id: id }, function(data){
      alert(data);
  });
}
```

**Errors:**
HttpException
EBADCSRFTOKEN: Invalid CSRF token

help me how to solve and post ajax request and get Adonis Js request...

Comment: How does your frontend look like? Are you using Adonis as an API? Are you using Adonis views with .edge? Are you using a form?

Comment: no ... i just using only one button...

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the token along with the request.

1. generate the token inside your view, you can put it on whatever you want, in the example below I'll store it as a data attribute:

```html
<div class="my-class" data-csrf-token="{{ csrfToken }}"></div>
```

2. get it with jQuery and pass it in the post request:

```
function QuestionEdit(id) {
  const token = $('.my-class').data('csrf-token');
  const params = { 
    id: id, 
    _csrf: token
  };

  $.post(origin + '/dashboard/api/questions/findby', params, function(data) {
    alert(data);
  });
}
```